# What is the difference between using a type as a different name and a type alias?

Tags: rust

What is the difference between

```
use hyper::status::StatusCode as Error;
```

and

```
type Error = hyper::status::StatusCode;
```

Are the any more differences between them except that `type` can be also `pub type`? What are the benefits between using one or another?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In case of simple types, like in your example, there doesn't seem to be any semantic difference. Moreover, there is a direct analogue with `use` to `pub type`, it's `pub use`:

```
// will be available to other modules
pub use hyper::status::StatusCode as Error;
```

However, there are differences in more complex cases. For example, you can define generic type aliases or aliases for specialized generic types:

```
type Result<T> = ::std::result::Result<T, MyError>;

type OptionI32 = Option<i32>;
```

The general idea is that you usually use type aliases because they are more powerful and suggest the intent more clearly, like with `Result`, and you use `use .. as ..` when you only want to import that specific name but it conflicts with something which is already in the current namespace:

```
use std::io::Read as StdRead;

trait Read: StdRead { ... }
```

Note that using path-qualified identifiers should be preferred to `use` renaming. The above is better written as

```
use std::io;

trait Read: io::Read { ... }
```

(unless `Read` methods are used for some concrete type in the same file, of course).

Using `use .. as ..` as a substitute for `type` (in case where it is possible) is uncommon and I think it should be avoided.